# Javascript execution sequence

Tags: javascript, sapui5

so I am trying to create a basic list using SAPUI5 and display it on browser. For that I have defined Page->app->Data ->Model->setData->standadrdList->List ->setModel -> add list to the Page. This did not work for me but there were no console errors.Then I did declare the object in sequence as [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/XOy6FHfGCNLcHdNoCvuc?p=preview). Can someone explain the logic behind this and why. Thanking you.

```
var oData ={
  Name: "Dinasour",
  Place : "Mammal"
};

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

oModel.setData(oData);

var oItem = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
  title : "{/Name}",
  description : "{/Place}"
});

var oList = new sap.m.List({
  headerText:"List Items in a Table",
  items:[
     oItem
    ]
});

oList.setModel(oModel);

var oPage = new sap.m.Page({
  title:"SAP LIST",
  content:[
     oList
    ]
});

var oApp = new sap.m.App({
  pages:[oPage]
}).placeAt("content1");
```

Comment: Relevant code should be here, not only on an external link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing a correct list binding.

1. Your data should be a Array like JSON
2. Define a template and binding path for your List

See the below code snippet and a working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/sAtnq4ZKMpwchOVEbVUI?p=preview).

```
var oData =
[ 
  {Name: "Dinasour", Place : "Mammal"},
  { Name: "Dinasour2",Place : "Mammal"},
  { Name: "Dinasour3",Place : "Mammal"}
];

//other code here

var oItem = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
   title : "{Name}",
   description : "{Place}"
});


var oList = new sap.m.List({
   headerText:"List Items in a Table",
   items: {
        path: "/",      //no curly brackets here!
        template: oItem
    }
});

//other code here
```